# How to cite a diploma thesis with biblatex/biber?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, thesis

The citation of a PhD thesis and a master's thesis works fine with `phdthesis` and `mathesis` respectively.
How can I cite a diploma thesis as "Diploma Thesis"?

The following MWE shows what I tried:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Thesis{Duck2000a,
    author      = {Dagobert Duck},
    title       = {Seashells as Currency after the Brexit},
    type        = {diplomathesis}, % mathesis and phdthesis work here
    institution = {University of Ducktown},
    year        = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

It compiles, however the string `diplomathesis` was not substituted by the correct localized string but printed raw instead.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new bibstring `diplomathesis` and give it a useful replacement text

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\NewBibliographyString{diplomathesis}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  diplomathesis = {diploma thesis},
}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Thesis{Duck2000a,
    author      = {Dagobert Duck},
    title       = {Seashells as Currency after the Brexit},
    type        = {diplomathesis}, % mathesis and phdthesis work here
    institution = {University of Ducktown},
    year        = {2019},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

The known strings are

> `bathesis` An expression equivalent to the term ‘Bachelor’s thesis’.
>
> `mathesis` An expression equivalent to the term ‘Master’s thesis’.
>
> `phdthesis` The term ‘PhD thesis’, ‘PhD dissertation’, ‘doctoral thesis’, etc.
>
> `candthesis` An expression equivalent to the term ‘Candidate thesis’. Used for ‘Candidate’ degrees that have no clear equivalent to the Master’s or doctoral level.

If it's just a one-off you can also exploit the fact that the `type` field is printed as literal if there is no bibstring with the appropriate name, so

```
    type        = {Diploma thesis},
```

might also work.